# Netbeans Code Assistance C++ - why stored in nbproject/configurations.xml

Tags: c++, git, netbeans

I´m currently trying to use Netbeans as IDE for our C++ projects.
When I open the project, and activate "Use Build Analyzer" under Code assistance (see image)
the nbproject/configurations.xml grows to more than 2MB. (not suitable for a single file in git that keeps changing all the time)
Is there a possibility to regenerate the full Code Assistance from a minimal configurations.xml file? Is it possible to store the Code Assistance files in a different file? Or any other help would be welcome

[image: Use Build Analyzer]

Comment: I used to have `nbproject` directory in the `.gitignore` file... and also I don't see the `settings.xml` in this directory

Comment: C++ Netbans and makefile project with build-configs?

Comment: All my projects don't have `nbproject/settings.xml` file - "C/C++ Project with Existing Sources" or others... My NetBeans stores configurations in `nbproject/configurations.xml`

Comment: Sorry, mixed it up, i meant configurations.xml all the time..